# Conditionally nest Django serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, serialization

So, I have a foreign key to my `User` model in many of my models. Now, the serializers for these models are nested, in that they include the entire user object rather than just the id. I have done so as shown bellow:

```py
class BadgeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Badge
        fields = '__all__'
```

It works as expected. However, I seldom find myself in a situation where I want just the id. I was wondering what is the best way to conditionally nest my `BadgeSerializer`...

Comment: What is the condition you want to apply ?

Comment: Certain serializers have the relevant `User` object and happen to include a list of `Badge`s as well. In such situations, I would like to avoid including duplicate info in my response, i.e. many instances of the same `User` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, the best solution I can think of is to have a non-nested BadgeSerializer, which includes only the user id. And then have a NestedBadgeSerializer (extending BadgeSerializer) which does nest the User model and include the entire user object.

```py
class BadgeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Badge
        fields = '__all__'

class NestedBadgeSerializer(BadgeSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Badge
        fields = '__all__'
```

I am NOT sure if that's the proper way though.

Comment: This is totally fine. It is ok to have multiple serializers for the same model.